# Change WooCommerce category pagination slug/permalink

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to change the slug for WooCommerce category pages? Even though I have all the updated translations, it still says "https://example.com/products/page/2/".

How can I change "page" to something else? "Page" is not in my language. I have tried some snippets for Wordpress, but WooCommerce only gives me a 404-page. I suspect WooCommerce needs its own code?

Answer (score -1):

As option you can do this:

First - add inside your functions file that code:

```
function set_new_pagination_base() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->pagination_base = 'your_new_base_instead_of_page';
}
add_action( 'init', 'set_new_pagination_base' );
```

Inside of 'your_new_base_instead_of_page' write what you want instead of word "page".

Second - in admin panel `your_siteurl/wp-admin/options-permalink.php` click button "save changes" without any change. That flash your rewrite rules.

Comment: That works for rewriting the permalink, but it does not work for WooCommerce. No products are loaded on page 2 after using this code.

Comment: @SpacePilot I tested that in my woocommerce and it's work.
What are the checkboxes do you have inside your "options-permalink" page? "Common Settings"( Post name in my ) and "Product permalinks"(Custom base - /product/ in my)? Maybe you have some active stuff that you tested to change "page"?

Comment: I have no active stuff that I have added to change "page" right now. I have the same in Common Settings as you. Under product permalinks I have custom base "produkt".

Comment: @SpacePilot Can you change the current theme and check the code there? Also disable all plugins except woocommerce? On my two sites, this code works, so you need to find what blocks it. If not helped try [Permalink Manager](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/permalink-manager/)